# Postfix not accepting mail from procmail in Centos7?

Tags: postfix, procmail

I have a Centos 7 server setup with Postfix, Spamassassin and procmail. It works fine, it receives and sends email , it passes it to the spam filter and delivers it to the required user or external email address.

The problem is, if I have a procmail recipe that processes mail, and then forwards it to an external address, this does not happen. On my previous Centos 6 server (with sendmail) this worked fine. The type of procmail recipe I am using is:

```
:0H
* ^X-Spam-Score:        * (\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
/dev/null


:0H
* ^X-Spam-Score:        * (\*\*\*\*\
$HOME/mail/Spam

:0
!email@example.com
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in both regexes. You cannot have an opening parenthesis without a closing parenthesis, and you cannot have your regex end with a backslash. (Or rather, the destination folder becomes part of your regex, but then you cannot have a recipe without a destination folder or other action.)

The parentheses seem superfluous here anyway; I guess you want

```
:0H
* ^X-Spam-Score:[     ]*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
/dev/null

:0H
* ^X-Spam-Score:[     ]*\*\*\*\*\*
$HOME/mail/Spam
```

where the two occurrences of `[    ]*` should have a space and a tab between the square brackets to match arbitrary whitespace before the literal asterisks; and the first recipe matches ten literal asterisks, anl the second, five. (Add more if you wanted more, or take away some if vice versa.)

For troubleshooting Procmail, defining a `LOGFILE` and examining the diagnostics in it is usually a good first step. There's a troubleshooting page at http://www.iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html with more guidance and other things you can try.

Comment: Then opening parenthesis is a literal character in the regex string. This recipe has been working correctly for 5 years or more. Are you suggesting I should escape the opening bracket? Thanks, Jim

Comment: Yes, you need `\(` to match a literal opening parenthesis. And again, define `LOGFILE` so you can see and react to any error messages from Procmail.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried it this and it's made no difference to either the spam filtering(which was, and is, fine) or the forwarding of procmail filtered emails as a forward. I sense this is a problem of procmail failing to pick up the email again after filtering; procmail is configured to use port 2525 and send via mailgun as this is a google cloud server with port 25 unavailable... any further ideas will be very welcome!

Comment: Procmail doesn't use a port number; I guess you mean Postfix is? If you are not currently managing to get Postfix to run Procmail when an incoming message arrives, that's a completely different question, where we need to see your Postfix configuration.

Comment: Or do you mean Procmail runs but `sendmail` in the forwarding action fails? Same thing though, we need to troubleshoot your `sendmail` (which is probably in your case a wrapper from the Postfix package).

Comment: Yes, postfix uses a port, not procmail. Promail is running fine and processing mail just as it always has, passing mail through spamassassin and filtering it depending on the result. There is one single problem. The forwarding line in the recipe does not result in the email actually being forwarded. With this exact same recipe it was working perfectly for many years on my previous server, albeit with sendmail rather than postfix. The only thing I can think of is that perhaps postfix is trying to do these forwards on port 25, which GCP does not allow? I do suspect this is a postfix issue.

Comment: This remains not at all a Procmail question then. Procmail simply runs `sendmail`; make sure you have configured your `sendmail` to submit to the right place. If it's the Postfix `sendmail` (which in any reasonable scenario it should be) it will have access to your Postfix configiration, but there might be options there you have forgotten to set. Does submission from the command line work? Then Procmail will work.

Comment: It wasnt framed as a procmail question, rather as a problem involving a process using procmail and postfix, which used to work in an identical setup before changing the outgoing smtp port to enable google cloud server. Not being an expert in Postfix Im not sure how to ensure that mails forwarded back to Postfix are then delivered out using this different port.